# Asking a question without being able to post relevant code

Tags: discussion, questions

I currently have a bug in my project which I am unable to track down. The issue is a SKNode inexplicably moving (or sometimes rotating) by itself.

I have reviewed my code multiple times and made a number of changes. I have googled for anyone having a similar problem but have found nothing helpful.

I am thinking about posting a question on SO regarding this issue but obviously I cannot post any relevant code as I do not know where the problem is or what could be causing it.

That being said, is it proper to post a SO question in this case?

Comment: How would anyone else be able to diagnose the problem, given such a question?  It sounds like the question would simply be unanswerable, as the problem described wouldn't be reproducible.

Comment: If I were in your case, I'd clone my project and start stripping out stuff until the issue went away.  Asking without providing enough information is practically useless.

Comment: @Servy - That is part of why I have been unable to solve the issue. I can post the code which creates the node but aside from that there really is no other specific code dedicated to this specific node. No movement, no modifications of any kind. The only similar issue I came across unfortunately did not shed any additional light onto my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800222/static-physics-body-still-moving-with-contact

Comment: @Will - That is an excellent recommendation. Something I have not tried yet but certainly will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it proper to post a SO question in this case?

Sure! Code isn't always (but usually) necessary and not always from the start. However, you usually can make an attempt to say, "This may be the problem area but I'm not sure" `<code snippet>`. "Please let me know if there is a more relevant part I should post" (or something similar).

You say,

> I have reviewed my code multiple times and made a number of changes. I have googled for anyone having a similar problem but have found nothing helpful.

**Show some self-debugging effort and avoid nasty "Have you even tried? What about this link?"**

Make sure to mention that you have searched for relevant posts/googles and possibly even post links to some of the places you've looked that don't seem to solve your problem. This will avoid people commenting with links that you have already tried.

**Be clear about the problem and what you are trying to achieve/prevent**

Just make sure that you are as clear about your problem as possible, what is happening/not happening that you want to happen/avoid, show your effort to resolve the issue, and (if possible) post *some relevant* code. If users see your effort, then a lot of them will ask to see a certain part of your code that they think might be relevant.

I would much rather have someone give a clear/short explanation of what they want, what they are getting, and what they have tried but not sure what part of the code to look in next than to say `<code snippet>` "it's not working, how to fix"

Comment: It's one thing to ask a conceptual question in which there simply *is no code*, and that can be answered without needing to see any code.  Here there is code, somewhere, that's causing the bug, he just doesn't know how to find it.  Asking such a question without code seems like it would simply be unanswerable.  No-code questions can be fine, in the right situation, but I don't think this is that kind of situation.

Comment: @Servy I agree. But I also think that if you don't know what code to post and you explain that then others who are more experienced can ask for certain parts of codes. If someone shows willingness to self-debug and that they simply don't know where the problem might be I will ask for say a certain class that may be causing the problem and not hold it against them. But that's also why my first part is there saying to post the most relevant the OP can think of and allow others to ask for additional parts.

Comment: I would also caution that if you can't get the bug down to (probable) spot that it might be too broad of a question (because the problem could be anywhere).  Depending on the problem, it could easily snowball into a long series of "fix all these things".