# Special section and/or new site for tips

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289124/asking-a-question-without-being-able-to-post-relevant-code) yesterday regarding whether or not I should post a question on SO without being in a position to post relevant code. I ended up being able to fix my issue (rather patch it) to a working state.

I suggest a section or a dedicated site for posting tips and problem solving steps would be nice to have. Obviously this would only be for those special issues which fall outside of the SO scope.

I am certain I was not the first (or last) to have had the issue I was dealing with but I am not able to share my solution due to the format of SO.

What does anyone else think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain canonical questions exist for tips on how to debug certain situations.

However, in general, these questions are by definition not answerable, which is why they aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. You may consider just writing it in your blog :)

Comment: Too bad. SO has a huge reach and I think it would provide added benefits but I thank you nevertheless for your answer and suggestion.

Comment: @sangony SO isn't really for long-form dissertation on various techniques. It would basically be aggregating mini-blog posts at that point. If you can phrase an appropriate question, go right ahead though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it is a good example that might help you.